# jq string interpolation with line breaks

Tags: jq

I have this expression:

```
echo '{"foo":"bar","boo":"moo"}' | jq -r '"\(.foo)|\(.boo)"'
bar|moo
```

Now, imagine that the filter is long, so I would like to break it into separate lines for readability while still producing the same output, conceptually like this:

```
jq '"
\(.foo)|
\(.boo)
"'
```

This however is not valid. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside of strings, your jq filter may have line breaks as you see fit. As for the strings, you can piece the single parts together using `+`:

```bash
echo '{"foo":"bar","boo":"moo"}' | jq -r '
  "\(.foo)|" +
  "\(.boo)"
'
```

```
bar|moo
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Tpz5-IWPLOD)

Comment: excellent,thsnks

Answer (score 2):

You might also wish to consider programmatic approaches, e.g.

```
  map_values( "\(.)" )
  | join("|")
```

or if you need to be picky about which keys to include, you could begin with:

```
  [with_entries(.value |= "\(.)")[]]
  | join("|")
```

or

```
  . as $in
  | reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k (""; . + "\($in[$k])|" )
  | sub("[|]$"; "")
```

or:

```
  . as $in
  | keys_unsorted as $keys
  | [ "\(.[$keys[0]])",
      ($keys[1:][] | "|\($in[.])" )] 
  | add
```

Comment: This works too and is educational, thank you peak!